# "Partial" factorials

Tags: permutations, factorial, hamiltonian-path

Other than double factorials and triple factorials, what is known about factorials which are missing some of their factors? For example, $1344=2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 7 \times 8$ which is $\frac{8!}{5 \times 6}$; I.e., $8!$ missing two factors - $5$ and $6$. This was encountered in studying the number of Hamiltonian circuits of a hypercube. A hypercube of dimension $4$ has $1344$ Hamiltonian circuits.

Comment: These are all special cases of the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_k-symbol)

Comment: Welcome to mse! Please use mathjax to format your questions/answers, so that users on different platforms will have an easier time reading them ^_^

Comment: Every number can be written as a factorial missing some of its factors! So in this much generality, nothing special can be said about such numbers.